# Hibernate: Getting Datasource from SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

Trying get datasource from Hibernate sessionFactory so that I can pass it to flyway factory.
Here is the code I am using:

```
SessionFactoryImpl factory = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory;
ConnectionProvider provider = factory.getConnectionProvider();
if(provider instanceof DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) {
            System.out.println(">>>Dude, this is hack");
}
```

Code never prints the sysout statement.

> > I am not Spring in my project, there is no way I can use `SessionFactoryUtils`.

Comment: Use session factory builder to build a session facktory.

Comment: I have sessionFactory, trying to get a dataSource from it.

Comment: It's not possible, session factory depends on datasource, create a datasource manually.

Comment: It should be possible since SpringFactoryUtils provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `DataSource` from the `DataSourceFactory` that you should have on your configuration class. DataSourceFactory has a [build method](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.8.1/dropwizard-db/apidocs/io/dropwizard/db/DataSourceFactory.html#build-com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry-java.lang.String-) that returns a ManagedDataSource which implements the DataSource interface.

You can see here an example (line 38): https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-hibernate/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/SessionFactoryFactory.java

**EDITED**

You need the jersey server running to get the environment. If you don't have the server running at the moment that you need the DataSource, you can create an instance by doing something like this:

`DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<Configuration>( Application.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("test-config.yml"));`

`ManagedDataSource ds = RULE.getConfiguration().getDataSourceFactory() .build(RULE.getEnvironment().metrics(), "migrations");`

Comment: How can I get hold of dropwizard's `Environment` without spinning off the jersey server?

Comment: I am aware of `DropwizardAppRule`. Trying to avoid it as it starts the jersey server itself.

Comment: I didn't find the way to get the dataSource without actually starting the server since the ```ManagedDataSource``` requires server related information, i.e. metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up doing this, which works fine for me:

```
final ManagedDataSource dataSource = config.getDataSourceFactory().build(new MetricRegistry(),
                 "flyway-service");
        final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setLocations(config.getFlywayFactory().getLocations().get(0));
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
        flyway.repair(); //
        flyway.migrate();
        flyway.clean();

        if (flyway.migrate() <= 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("migration failed!");
        }
```

Here `config` is Dropwizard which I got by parsing configuration yaml file.